# How to convert text with multi lines to JSON Format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a multi line string below: How to convert this into JSON using Javascript?

```
Q1. This is the tile of the question
A.  Option A
B.  Option B
C.  Option C
D.  Option D
E.  Option E
Ans. E

Q2. This is the tile of the question
A.  Option A
B.  Option B
C.  Option C
D.  Option D
E.  Option E
Ans. A
```

Comment: What are your expected output and what have you tried?

Comment: The above specified data format is returned by a HTTP Sservice. I wanna use this data in my javascript application. I have tried approaches similar to csv to json conversion but I am not able to parse this into JSON array.

Answer (score 1):

To format new lines in JSON you only need to replace them with `\n` special character. If you want to convert your text to JSON format you can use  the 
`JSON.stringify()` function

```
jsonData = JSON.stringify(`Q1. This is the tile of the question
A.  Option A
B.  Option B
C.  Option C
D.  Option D
E.  Option E
Ans. E

Q2. This is the tile of the question
A.  Option A
B.  Option B
C.  Option C
D.  Option D
E.  Option E
Ans. A`);
```

The result will be:

```
"Q1. This is the tile of the question\nA.  Option A\nB.  Option B\nC.  Option C\nD.  Option D\nE.  Option E\nAns. E\n\nQ2. This is the tile of the question\nA.  Option A\nB.  Option B\nC.  Option C\nD.  Option D\nE.  Option E\nAns. A"
```

If you want a more structured way to store this data (question, option and answers) you can use a JSON structure like this:

```
[
  {
    "question": "Question 1",
    "a": "Option A",
    "b": "Option B",
    "c": "Option C",
    "d": "Option D",
    "answer": "c"
  },
  {
    "question": "Question 2",
    "a": "Option A",
    "b": "Option B",
    "c": "Option C",
    "d": "Option D",
    "answer": "b"
  }
]
```